# Python: Truncating column width with Datareader

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

I am setting up a *matplotlib graph* with **stock price** and **volume**. The graph will be getting the data from `pandas datareader`.

My issue is the volume is very high compared to the price so a graph of them would look very unproportional, and I cant scale it due to constantly changing stocks.

**How can I truncate the width of each column so that instead of say '10' digits each row only displays '5'?**.

I've tried to separate each column into a string and use split however my issue was finding a way to append them back into a dataframe.

-- sidenote: If there is a way to get volume as a bar graph while price is a line that would be awesome.

```
start = datetime.date(2017, 12, 29)
end = datetime.date(2018, 12, 29)
f = web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'iex', start, end)


f = f.head[10]
price = f.open
volume = f.volume
time = f.shape[0]

plt.plot(time,price)
plt.plot(time, volume)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set twin axes with different scale.

```
start = datetime.date(2017, 12, 29)
end = datetime.date(2018, 12, 29)
import pandas_datareader.data as web
f = web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'iex', start, end)   
f = f.head()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(x = f.index, height = f.volume/1000, width = 0.3)
ax1.set_ylabel('volumn in 1000s', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(f.index, f.open, 'g')
ax2.set_ylabel('open price', color='g')
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='g')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will try that out!